# Symfony2: Check the user object in the controllers, best practice

Tags: php, security, symfony

Is it a good idea to check in the controller that the object called by `getUser()` of `security.context` service is actually an object of my custom user class?

```
public function editAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof \Acme\UserBundle\User) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user doesn't have access');
    }

    // work with $user
    // ....
```

The only thing that is guaranteed is that `getUser()` returns an object that implemented `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`, nothing else, right?

This means that the controller may potentially receive any type of object (a token anonymous maybe) so if I pass (without control it) the object directly to the view that subsequently call `{{ user.biography }}`, which is implemented only in `Acme\UserBundle\User` class .., I'd be making an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea if your configuration allows that possibility. This could happen if you allow anonymous users or have more than one type implemented.

Of you implement multiple user types it might be a good idea to make them share a common interface. You can also override the "getRole" method on each class so each type returns a extra role defining it's type and then use access control to filter undesired types out.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this type of condition.

```
public function editAction()
{
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return  $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('frontend_cart_login'));
    }
...
```

You can choose your own "ROLE" defined in your security.yml file.

Comment: but can happen that there are ROLE_* shared between multiple user class?

Comment: in this cas, you can add a ROLE for each user class. More over, manage a ROLE for your feature. For instance ROLE_USER_ADMIN or ROLE_USER_CUSTOMER and a functionnal ROLE_EDITOR.